# Make search result returned only from tags!

Tags: search, tags

I was trying to search entire Google, Yahoo and Bing, but also can't get the answer i want. That is why i am here to ask for help.

Now, i make searches on my website, the results are returned from Title and Content. Is it possible to get it return from Tags only(without plugin if possible)? Appreciate your help from everybody does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the [Search Everything plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) and go from there. It won't exclude all post title and content, but it will enable searching in tags. Perhaps you can see how they accomplish it and modify from there. I imagine it will entail some direct SQL manipulation via the query filters [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where), [`posts_join`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join), [`posts_request`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_request), etc..

Comment: Thanks Milo for reply! But is there any other way we can do it with just in function file(php code)?